# Can't Connect to Local Mosquitto Broker From Real Android Device

Tags: android, android-emulator, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I created a MQTT broker using Mosquitto library (version - 1.6.12). and created Android mobile app, which acts as paho clients(Libraries Used - 'libs/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar', 'libs/org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.1.1.jar')

Trying to connect android app to the local Mosquitto broker. I'm able to connect through Android emulator Getting Socket issue When I try with real android device.

**Android Code:**

```
        MqttAndroidClient client;
        String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();

        //Since broker is running in the same system I gave my local IP-ADDRESS - 192.168.0.100
        //Port - 1883

        client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://192.168.0.100:1883", clientId);
        try {

            MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
            options.setKeepAliveInterval(60);
            Log.d(TAG, "MqttConnectOptions : "+options.toString());
            IMqttToken token = client.connect(options);

            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure ");
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Android Studio Logs:**

```
2020-10-06 20:27:31.775 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err: MqttException (0) - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.100 (port 1883) from /192.168.0.102 (port 37459) after 30000ms
2020-10-06 20:27:31.778 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.779 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:715)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.779 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.779 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.780 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.780 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.780 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.781 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.785 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.100 (port 1883) from /192.168.0.102 (port 37459) after 30000ms
2020-10-06 20:27:31.786 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.786 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.786 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.786 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.787 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.787 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.787 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.788 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.788 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:84)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.788 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701)
2020-10-06 20:27:31.788 23972-23972/com.exam.mqttwithlibs W/System.err:     ... 6 more
```

In above image  192.168.0.100 - System's IP  and  192.168.0.102 - Android device IP

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please do not post images of the text of the error, post the actual text and format it using the toolbar. As it is it is unreadable (especially for people using screen readers). Also have you checked you can connect to the broker from any other machine on the local network?

Comment: I updated logs with text message, Thanks for the correction. I'm able to connect to local Mosquitto broker only through android emulator

Comment: Thanks, but the question about being able to connect from other machines on the network is to check if it's a firewall problem. The emulator will be connecting from inside the firewall.

Comment: No, Not able to connect from other machines. Can you please clarify how the firewall come in to picture here?

Comment: The firewall will be dropping the packets from the Android device, try with the firewall turned off or with port 1883 opened

Comment: https://bytesofgigabytes.com/networking/how-to-open-port-in-windows/ - Now able to connect from real android device also by opening 1883 port, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Port 1883 by following this link https://bytesofgigabytes.com/networking/how-to-open-port-in-windows/ solves this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mosquitto as a server on MacOS, you need edit the config file at `/opt/homebrew/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

```
listener 1883 -- Specify port number
allow_anonymous true
```

Then restart Mosquitto